# как убрать обводку редактируемой ячейки и добавить обводку выделяющих ячеек таблицы

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qtablewidget

Пример того как это должно выглядит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я смотрел в [таблице стилей](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html#style-sheet-usage) и в примерах стилей таблиц но это не дало результата

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
        self.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)  #  Убирает сеточку выделения
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet('''QTableWidget::item:selected
{      
    
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #e4e2e2;
}

        ''')
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: метод ```.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)``` убирает не сетку, а фокус что лишает кнопок навигации, а сделать её не видимой можно с помощью класса ```NoFocusDelegate```. Также вы задали обводку выделяемым ячейкам а не выделяемому полю